# Question about a double series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Calculate

$$\sum_{j=0}^2 \sum_{k=j}^2 k^j $$

So what I have is, since j=0 and k=j, k must also start with zero, right? (I am confused at this part)

$$\sum_{j=0}^2 0^j + 1^j + 2^j = $$

$$ =0^0 + 1^0 + 2^0 + 0^1 + 1^1 + 2^1 + 0^2 + 1^2 + 2^2  $$

Could someone check whether this is correct, and what exactly do I write instead of $0^0$? Some say 1 , some say undefined?

Comment: That is not correct. Writing $\displaystyle\sum_{k=j}^2 k^j$ as $f(j)$ should help. Your sum can be written as 
$$\sum_{j=0}^2  f(j)=f(0)+f(1)+f(2) =\sum_{k=0}^2 k^0+ \sum_{k=1}^2 k^1+ \sum_{k=2}^2 k^2$$

Comment: @mathlove: Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not correct, because the inner summation starts at $j$, not at $0$. When $j=0$ the inner summation is $0^0+1^0+2^0$, but when $j=1$ it’s $1^1+2^1$, and when $j=2$ it’s just $2^2$. Thus, the whole thing is

$$\left(0^0+1^0+2^0\right)+\left(1^1+2^1\right)+2^2\,,$$

which is

$$(1+1+1)+(1+2)+4=10\,.$$

the normal convention is that $0^0=1$.

Comment: Dear Brian, thank you so much! You can not imagine how much your comments have already helped me (not only the ones under my own posts!).

Comment: @Parinn: You’re very welcome!